# Galaxy S4: Some apps install. Some result in *app name* can't be installed in the device's install location

Tags: applications, internal-storage

For example I can successfully download apps, but then with some apps get this message.

Clearly this is not a storage problem and my software is updated.

Comment: are you  telling  about download and install apk's? or from play store?

Comment: From the play store